# XML Syntax when Using Colon (:), in Tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

I am working on a mobile application and have to read a xml feed and parse the information. There it has a special tag as this `<dc:creator> Jonethon Owens </dc:creator>`

In C# I am using LINQ to XML and don't know how to exactly deal with this type of a tag to parse and get the information.

If someone can explain how to achieve this, really appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: See if 'dc' has been declared as a namespace at the top of the xml.

Comment: In the top of the xml document it says xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"

Comment: So you got the answer from FailedDev (not failing)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the namespace prefix.

```
XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";


var query = from lst in XElement.Load(@"foo.xml").Elements(dc +"creator")

            select ...
```

Comment: Thanks FailedDev, I am getting an exception "null object". May be I gave XNamespace dc = "purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/". Because in the top of the XML file it indicates  xmlns:dc="purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/". Is it something else should assign to XNamespace dc.

Comment: @JibW No this is your namespace. Your are getting the exception by some other piece of code, which you are not showing.

Comment: All the other XML tags are normal. They don't have Semicolon. So others work fine when I comment [Creator = (string)result.Element(dc+"creator").Value]. I gave XNamespace dc = "purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" as this. I am not sure the value I assigned to the dc is correct

Comment: @JibW If we don't see the .xml we can't help you.

Comment: @JibW The updated answer has the correct namespace. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: can you please give me the full query